# How do i call a webservice through a java class?

Tags: java, web-services

I am working on AlertingApi(generating alerts for webservice call) where i need to call a webservice directly through java class.But I'm getting an issue here that is,whenever the main class for web service is called,this new class of mine is somehow getting called too. Due to which when the service gets hit,again the webservice is hit inside the class making the service hit twice.
Any suggestions on how do i separately make a web service call so that i can proceed with my alerting stuff?

Comment: Can you please elaborate question with codes , it will be easy to understand the problem.

Comment: It is difficult to elaborate the scenario but what i want is to know a way through which we can do Metrics Alerting for the Web Service(Producer Web service) which is loosely coupled and isolated from Web service main class.

Comment: Which kind of web services are we talking about? REST or SOAP? Do you want to call them in pure Java or is it ok to use third party libraries/frameworks?

Comment: It is in SOAP.I can use both of them,either pure Java or third party libraries/frameworks.